# VB .NET Framework ComboBox Dropdown List Immediately Closes When Clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a ComboBox used as a dropdown list.  If I tab into the ComboBox, the dropdown list opens normally.  However, if the focus is on another control & I click on the arrow on the ComboBox to open the list, it opens but then immediately closes.  If I click again, it opens & stays open.  Repeatedly clicking on the arrow opens & closes the list as expected as long as the ComboBox has the focus.  Once focus changes to another control, the aberrant behavior repeats.

Here are all of the event handlers I have for the ComboBox:

```
    Private Sub cboFelony_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboFelony.Enter
        If Not IsNothing(CurrentApplication) AndAlso Not DisplayingApplication Then
            cboFelony.DroppedDown = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboFelony_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cboFelony.KeyPress
        ' Ignore all keys except N, Y, & space.
        If Not IsNothing(CurrentApplication) AndAlso Not DisplayingApplication Then
            cboFelony.DroppedDown = True
            Select Case UCase(e.KeyChar.ToString)
                Case "N", "Y"
                Case " " : cboFelony.SelectedIndex = (cboFelony.SelectedIndex + 1) Mod cboFelony.Items.Count
                Case CR : GoToNextControl()
                Case Else : e.Handled = True
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboFelony_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboFelony.Leave
        Dim strFelony As String = ""

        If Not IsNothing(CurrentApplication) AndAlso Not DisplayingApplication Then
            Select Case cboFelony.SelectedIndex
                Case 0 : strFelony = ""
                Case 1 : strFelony = "N"
                Case 2 : strFelony = "Y"
            End Select
            If strFelony <> CurrentApplication.FelonyConviction Then
                CurrentApplication.FelonyConviction = strFelony
                If NetworkIsActive Then
                    MyNetwork.SendApplicationPropertyMessage(CurrentApplication.ControlNr,
                                                             LicenseApplication.FIELD_FELONY,
                                                             CurrentApplication.FelonyConviction)
                End If
            End If
            cboFelony.SelectionLength = 0
            cboFelony.SelectionStart = 0
        End If
    End Sub
```

I have unsuccessfully tried finding the event that is closing the dropdown list.

Comment: I haven't tested but I suspect that it is the fact that you're setting `DroppedDown` to `True` on `Enter`. When you click the control, the `Enter` event will be raised first and that will drop the list down, then the `Click` event will be raised and that will close the list up again.